# Split de String em C++

Tags: json, c++, string, qt, split

Pessoal estou querendo da um split na seguinte String em C++

```
[
 {
  "Nome":"Gabriel",
  "idade": 23
 }
]
```

estou fazendo da seguinte forma...

Recebo esse json através de uma consulta `get` e armazenando em uma string para poder da o split (OBS: não sei se teria alguma forma melhor de fazer isso)

```
run = json.split(",");
```

`json[0]` está me retornando meu primeiro elemento com o `[` e `{`

```
[ { "Nome":"Gabriel"
```

como faço para pegar somente o nome `gabriel` ou até mesmo o valor `23` da idade

OBS: Estou usando o Qt creator 4.8 onde ainda não dá suporte para se trabalhar com json, infelizmente.

Comment: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: QT: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Comment: `split` ? Não quer dizer `parse` ? Regra geral a ação de interpretar um JSON se chama de `parse`.

Comment: isso, porém no ambiente Qt não me da suporte pra trabalhar com json.

Uma forma que encontrei porem não sei se é a melhor forma de se fazer isso, foi pegar esse json e colocar em um QString e a partir disso faço o split 
Qt só da suporte a json na versão 5

Answer (score -1):

Existe algumas bibliotecas JSON para C++, mas se não quiser usar, pode fazer um pequeno parser:

```
string strJSON = string("..aqui vai o json.")
string strProp = string("\"idade\":");
int szJSON = strJSON.size();

//encontra a posição de inicio da propriedade:
int pos = strJSON.find(strProp);
if (pos == std::string::npos)
    throw string("propriedade idade não encontrada");
pos+=strProp.size();//pula a parte que é igual ao strProp, logo antes do ':'

//pular caracteres não numéricos
while(pos<szJSON && (strJSON[pos] < '0' || strJSON[pos] > '9')) pos++;

//salva posição onde inica os números 
int startPos = pos;

//pular caracteres numéricos apenas
while(pos<szJSON && (strJSON[pos] > '0' || strJSON[pos] < '9')) pos++;

//se o ponteiro inicial é igual ao final, os chegarão dois estão no final da string sem encontrar nenhum numero
if (startPos == pos)
    throw string("sequencia numérica não encontrada");

//pegar a string com caracteres numéricos..
string strIdade = strJSON.substr(startPos, pos - startPos);
//converte-la para inteiro
int idade = atoi(strIdade.c_str());
```

*obs.: esse código não válida o JSON, apenas pega a primeira sequencia numérica após a propriedade escolhida.

*obs 2.: não esqueça de #incluide <string> e using namespace std